# Custom UIView with dynamic height on Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, uilabel

I want to implement custom UIView (from code) with dynamic height, based on content (similar to UILabel). I can do this by implementing `intrinsicContentSize` - and it seems to work correctly, but...

When I am adding my custom view to view controller on storyboard, I've got error (missing height constraint) - even when during launch everything seems to resize correctly.

When you add UILabel to storyboard you don't have to specify height, there are no errors. 
How to achieve the same behavior for custom UIView (I want to use it in storyboard)?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If someone will need the solution:

I just found that there is "Intrinsic Size" property in Storyboard - you just need to set it to "Placeholder" and set some values just for Interface Builder...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this. :)

Answer (score 0):

i come to know that you are creating by programmatically.
try to use the following code and improve it in your requirement . Best of luck.
NSDictionary* views = @{@"view" : self.view};

```
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
```